# How to use insert indexing position in starting 3 position Code dynamically instead of multiple if statement

Tags: vb.net

I want to use dynamic code because when we use 100 levels I can not write `If` statement 100 times. How can we write code dynamic if level is any value, for example 5 then insert 5 starting index position like for position 0-->A, 1-->B, 2-->C, 3-->D, 4-->E. Up to index position 5 I have set:

```
Dim Fur As String
Dim FAry As Array

If Levels = 5 Then
    FAry = Split(Fur.Insert(0, "A,B,C,D,E,"), ",")

ElseIf Levels = 4 Then
    FAry = Split(Fur.Insert(0, "A,B,C,D,"), ",")

ElseIf Levels = 3 Then
    FAry = Split(Fur.Insert(0, "A,B,C,"), ",")

ElseIf Levels = 2 Then
    FAry = Split(Fur.Insert(0, "A,B,"), ",")

ElseIf Levels = 1 Then
    FAry = Split(Fur.Insert(0, "A,"), ",")

ElseIf Levels = 0 Then
    FAry = Split(Fur, ",")

End If
```

Comment: As the English alphabet only has 26 letters, what characters are to be used for `levels` > 26?

Comment: Do you mean something like `FAry = Enumerable.Range(0, Levels).Select(Function(n) ChrW(n + 65)).ToArray()`? (or `ChrW(n + AscW("A"))`, if that's more clear)

Comment: any dummy data we can insert or else "AA","AB" like that combination also. or for every index position we can insert directly 0. like for Position 0-->0, 1-->0, 2-->0 etc this would be easy. my target is only one if levels = any no. (Example 10) then set for 10 starting indexing position should be set with 0 or any value.

Answer (score 1):

That is an unusual way to approach the basic problem of "I want an array that has N numbers in, counted up in letters".

Instead let's make a function that can convert a number into any base:

```
Public Shared Function ToBase(base10 As Long, Optional baseChars As String = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTSUVWXYZ") As String

    If baseChars.Length < 2 Then Throw New ArgumentException("baseChars must be at least 2 chars long")

    If base10 = 0 Then Return baseChars(0)

    Dim isNegative = base10 < 0
    Dim radix = baseChars.Length
    Dim index As Integer = 64 'because it's how long a string will be if the basechars are 2 long (binary)
    Dim chars(index) As Char '65 chars, 64 from above plus one for sign if it's negative

    base10 = Math.Abs(base10)


    While base10 > 0
        chars(index) = baseChars(base10 Mod radix)
        base10 \= radix

        index -= 1
    End While

    If isNegative Then
        chars(index) = "-"c
        index -= 1
    End If

    Return New String(chars, index + 1, UBound(chars) - index)

End Function
```

Now let's use it to generate 100 "numbers", in base 26 (A=0,B=1,...,J=9,K=10,...,Z=25,BA=26). You should note that the next "number" after "Z" is "BA" not "AA", for the same reason that 9 + 1 is 10, not 00; "A" is the "zero" character so it doesn't lead. If this is confusing, consider that "Z" isn't "Z" it's "AZ", like 9 isn't 9 it's 09. Adding one to 09 becomes 10. Adding one to "AZ" is "BA"

```
Dim x as New List(Of String)(100)
For i = 0 to 99
  x.Add(ToBase(i, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))
Next i
```

You get a list with this in:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,
BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,BG,BH,BI,BJ,BK,BL,BM,BN,BO,BP,BQ,BR,BS,BT,BU,BV,BW,BX,BY,BZ,
CA,CB,CC,CD,CE,CF,CG,CH,CI,CJ,CK,CL,CM,CN,CO,CP,CQ,CR,CS,CT,CU,CV,CW,CX,CY,CZ,
DA,DB,DC,DD,DE,DF,DG,DH,DI,DJ,DK,DL,DM,DN,DO,DP,DQ,DR,DS,DT,DU,DV
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.copyto?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_CopyTo_System_Int32__0___System_Int32_System_Int32_
for more details on the .CopTo method.

```
Private Function GetArray(Levels As Integer) As String()
    'Create a List(Of T) with all the elements you want to use
    Dim lst As New List(Of String) From {"A,", "B,", "C,", "D,", "E,", "F,", "G,", "H,", "I,", "J,"}
    'Declare an array of the proper size
    Dim FAry(Levels - 1) As String
    'CopyTo(Int32, T[], Int32, Int32)
    lst.CopyTo(0, FAry, 0, Levels)
    Return FAry
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MyNewArray = GetArray(5)
    For Each item In MyNewArray
        Debug.Print(item)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a function to convert the value of `levels` to a list of codes (letters). It is easiest to use a List(Of String) for that instead of an Array because a List expands automatically when you add more entries to it. You will also need a function to convert a value to the letter code.

For example the basic console application:

```
Module Module1

    Function LetterCode(n As Integer) As String
        If n = 0 Then Return String.Empty
        If n > 26 * 27 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Argument greater than 26*27 (702) - no more two-letter codes available after ""ZZ"".")
        End If

        Dim lc As String = Chr(65 + ((n - 1) Mod 26))

        If n > 26 Then
            lc = Chr(65 + ((n - 1) \ 26 - 1) Mod 26) & lc
        End If

        Return lc

    End Function

    Function LetterCodes(n As Integer) As List(Of String)
        Dim lcs As New List(Of String)
        For i = 1 To n
            lcs.Add(LetterCode(i))
        Next

        Return lcs

    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Dim fur = "1,2,3" ' example data

        Dim levels = 67
        Dim furParts = fur.Split({","c})
        Dim fAry = If(levels = 0, furParts, LetterCodes(levels).Concat(furParts)).ToArray()

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", fAry))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AU,AV,AW,AX,AY,AZ,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,BG,BH,BI,BJ,BK,BL,BM,BN,BO,1,2,3

Please note that instead of `.ToArray()` you could use `.ToList()`, because a List is more versatile, or even omit it to give you an IEnumerable(Of String) which won't be evaluated until it is used, if that was sensible.